# Passing parent props to children

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I've been trying to create a "customable form template" using Vue.js. The logic I wanted to apply is as follows:

- I created a "custom-form" component that takes a `vueForm` prop and renders a form. The `vueForm` prop is an object with a specific structure, containing `fields` and `errors` keys.
- I created a "custom-input" component that takes multiple props, including the `value` (for the v-model) and `errors`... **which happens to be available in our `vueForm` object mentionned before**

My problem is that I can't seem to access the `vueForm` object passed as prop in the `custom-form` FROM my `custom-input` :(. I've tried adding it to data, using provide/inject, etc. No success so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks

Below a sample of the code:

**COMPONENTS**

```js
// PARENT COMPONENT
Vue.component("custom-form", {
    props: {
        vueForm: Object,
    },
    template:
        `<form :id="vueForm.id" :method="vueForm.method" action="">
            <slot></slot>
        </form>`,
});

// CHILD COMPONENT
Vue.component("custom-input", {
    props: {
        name: String,
        type: String,
        placeholder: String,
        icon: String,
        value: [String, Number, Date],
        errors: Array,
    },
    template:
        `<div class="field">
            <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                    <i :class="icon"></i>
                </span>
                <input
                    class="input"
                    :type="type"
                    :name="name"
                    :placeholder="placeholder"
                    v-on:input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
                >
                <span class="icon is-small is-right" v-if="errors.length">
                    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
                </span>
                <p class="help is-danger" v-for="message in errors">
                    {{message}}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>`,
});
```

**VUE**

```js
var mainVue = new Vue({
    el: "main",
    data: {
        loginTab: true,
        authForm: {
            id: "user-form",
            method: "POST",
            errors: {
                non_field_errors: [],
                email: [],
                password: [],
                confirm_password: [],
            },
            fields: {
                email: "",
                password: "",
                confirm_password: "",
            },
        },
    },
});
```

**HTML**

```html
<custom-form :vue-form="authForm"> <!-- Passing authFrom as our vueForm prop -->

    <custom-input
        name="email"
        type="email"
        placeholder="Email"
        icon="fas fa-envelope"
        :value="vueForm.fields.email"  <!-- vueForm is not defined :( -->
        :errors="vueForm.errors.email" <!-- vueForm is not defined :( -->
    ></custom-input>

    <button
        class="button is-primary"
        @click.prevent="submitForm"
    >
        <span class="icon is-small">
            <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
        </span>
        <span>{% trans "Submit" %}</span>
    </button>

</custom-form>
```

Comment: The way you choosed is not the best approach to create components. But why dont you write `:value="authForm.fields.email"` ? And if you need to use vueForm, try to use $emit to export data from component .

Comment: Since I have several inputs, I didn't want to write "authForm" for each input, but rather store its value in the "custom-form" component, and use it for each input. That way, if I were to change the name of "authForm", I would have to change it only in the "custom-form" input and not every single <input>.

You mentioned my approach isn't ideal. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bubble date from your child component you can use the $emit function as per the official documentation:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that is not what my problem is about. I want to CREATE the "custom-input" component by passing a PROP that is already a PROP from its parent.

Comment: I see what you mean now, if it says vueForm is not defined you can debug it using vue development tools extension to see the actual value of the vueForm property in the form component. Also when you are going deeper it's recommended to start using vuex to handle the data exchange between components.